# How to configure NodeJS AWS SDK using S3 Client library with Proxy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to determine how to pass the proxy configuration to the @aws-sdk/s3-client library, not to be confused with the @aws-sdk/s3 library.

Typically, using any traditional libraries, you can use the following to set up the proxy as described by the documentation like so:

```
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {
    agent: HttpsProxyAgent('http://proxy.com'),
  },
});
```

However, with the s3-client, it looks like it has a S3ClientConfig as an argument to the S3Client constructor.

Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/globals.html#s3clientconfig

Has any out there ever got this working?

In case your wondering, I'm being ask to use this s3-client library.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Are process.env.HTTP_PROXY || process.env.http_proxy set ? (2) Is required aws configuration loaded before update? and (3) What error do you get?

Comment: @amitd - thanks for your response. 

1.) Yes, they're set. 

2.) This is what I'm looking to discover.  I am trying to find the equivalent for the s3-client version. 

3.) ETIMEDOUT - in other words, it can't access the internet because its being blocked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS SDK can´t connect behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979212/aws-sdk-can%c2%b4t-connect-behind-corporate-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I've done it using the v3 libs:

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"; 
import { NodeHttpHandler } from "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler";
import ProxyAgent from "proxy-agent";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
        httpsAgent: ProxyAgent('http://yourproxyhere.com')
    })
});
```

You can also use the [aws-sdk-v3-js-proxy](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-v3-js-proxy) wrapper.

Comment: I just realized that the link posted in the comments above said the exact same thing...sigh